# HTTP content to string/model

Tags: c#, http-headers, json.net

I have an object.
I'am sending it this to my api project this way :

```
mymodel obj = new mymodel();
obj.prop = "this";
obj.prop2 = "prop2";

var content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
var buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(content);
var byteContent = new ByteArrayContent(buffer);
byteContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

string response = "";

using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
var rez = await client.PostAsync(uri + myenum.Insert, byteContent).ConfigureAwait(false);
response = rez.ToString();
}
```

In my api method i want to convert that string or http content again to model.

```
[ActionName("Insert")]
[HttpGet]
public bool Insert(string obj)
{
try
{
mymodel model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<mymodel>(obj);
```

How to handle object i'am sending with postasync in my api method ?

Any help ?

Answer (score 0):

First you cannot use PostAsync on a HTTPGet method.

Second, I dont understand what you mean. If you are using json then you dont have to do anything. Just have a simple client method as such:

```
public async Task<TResult> PostAsync<TResult, TInput>(string uriString, TInput payload = null) where TInput : class
    {
        var uri = new Uri(uriString);
        using (var client = GetHttpClient())
        {
            var jsonContent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payload, Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver() });
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(uri, new StringContent(jsonContent, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
            if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                //Log.Error(response.ReasonPhrase);
                return default(TResult);
            }
            var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TResult>(json);
        }
    }
```

And you can just add the same object to your API like

```
[ActionName("Insert")]
[HttpPost]
public bool Insert(YourObjectClass obj)
{
    try
   {
      ....code....
   }
}
```

Comment: You can just write `return default;` instead of `return default(TResult);`